# Delete Contact From particular list from constant contact API

Tags: php, constantcontact

I have integrate the constant contact API. It's  working fine while adding contact to particular list. I have created 5 different lists. When I am adding contact to particular list
I want to delete this contact form other list if it is already present.

Please suggest if you have any solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the PHP SDK the easiest way to do this is probably to access the lists property of the contact object and remove the list objects that you no longer want the user to be subscribed to.

You can also clear all lists as such:

```
// Clear all lists
$contact->lists = array();

// Add the particular list you want
$contact->addList('listId');

// Update Contact
$ctct->updateContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact, false);
```

Otherwise you can also use the `deleteContactFromList($accessToken, $contact, $list)` method, but this takes a little bit more work as it requires both the contact entity and the list entity (verses just the ID).  So essentially once you got the contact entity it would look like this:

```
$contact = $ctct->getContactByEmail(ACCESS_TOKEN, $email_address)->results[0];
$listToDelete = new ContactList($listId);
$ctct->deleteContactFromList(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact, $listToDelete);
```

Hope that helps!

Mike

Comment: Just want to note that `$ctct = new ConstantContact(APIKEY);` Using the suggested `deleteContactFromList()` worked great!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation here [Bulk Activities - Remove Contacts Endpoint](https://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/bulk_activities_api/bulk-activities-remove-contacts-api.html).

I've taken different approach.

I will layout the logic and the use of right CC API method, of course, you can retrieve list_id dynamically and make additional checks (for i.e. check if the user is really a member of the list), but for this purpose I am trying to show only how to remove contact form the list, that is the main thought here.

Let's start.

1. in my `composer.json` I have this:

`{
    "require": {
        "constantcontact/constantcontact": "1.3.2"
    }
}`

I had to use old [Constant Contact API](https://github.com/constantcontact/php-sdk/tree/v1-master) because of the clients server infrastructure which has **PHP version *5.3.29*** installed.

2. In terminal navigate to your source root and run `composer update`.
3. When the dependencies are installed we are ready to go.
4. In let's take for example my `index.php` I would put this:

   ```
   require_once('/vendor/autoload.php');
   use Ctct\ConstantContact;
   use Ctct\Services;
   use Ctct\Components\Contacts\Contact;
   use Ctct\Exceptions\CtctException;

   define("APIKEY", "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE");//Write your API key
   define("ACCESS_TOKEN", "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE");//Write your Access Token here

   $cc = new ConstantContact(APIKEY);
   $ca = new Services\ActivityService(APIKEY);
   $error = 0;

   try {
       $response = $cc->getContactByEmail(ACCESS_TOKEN, $email);
       if (empty($response->results)) {
           //Create new contact if needed
       } else {
           $action = "Remove contact from subscribe list";
           $contact = $response->results[0];
           try {
               $ca->addRemoveContactsFromListsActivity(
                   ACCESS_TOKEN, 
                   array($contact->email_addresses[0]->email_address), 
                   array('1894839946')//List Id from which you want the contact to be removed from
               );
           } catch (Exception $e) {
               var_dump($e->getMessage());
           }
           /*
            * The third parameter of updateContact defaults to false, but if this were set to true it would tell
            * Constant Contact that this action is being performed by the contact themselves, and gives the ability to
            * opt contacts back in and trigger Welcome/Change-of-interest emails.
            *
            * See: http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contacts-api/contacts-index.html#opt_in
            */
           $returnContact = $cc->updateContact(ACCESS_TOKEN, $contact, true);
       }         
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       var_dump($e->getMessage());
   }
   ```

Hope it will help someone. Cheers.